# Windows Phone 7 Notifications/Pop/Toasts

Tags: notifications, windows-phone-7, toast

If there a way to display a normal Notification/Toast/Popup in Windows Phone 7, which is not a Push Notification?

All I want to do is to be able to give the user a message when something occurs...

Comment: I think what you need is in the following article [http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wish to display something while your application is not running in the foregorund. Because, when your application runs in the foreground, you can do whatever you want.

Your application **can't** run in the background, therefore you don't really have any means of invoking anything. This means you can't really display a message when somethien occurs.

What exectly occurs on the phone that you need to notify the user? Is that really not back-end related?

There are [two great sample chapters](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/preview.html) on Windows Phone and Silverlight for Windows Phone on the [LearningWindosPhone.com](http://www.learningwindowsphone.com/) site. There is great Windows [Phone Trainng material](http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/WP7TrainingKit/) , and dont forget the [Windows Phone Develoeprs Blog](http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/wpdev/default.aspx)

Comment: Yeah i suppose there is no need for Notifications like in Android, unless you have a Push Client and use Push Notifications. Ah well, silly no multitasking!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MessageBox.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms599804%28v=VS.95%29.aspx), though this creates a modal dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the notification while your app is not running (but when you're doing some background work) then I believe this is what you want:

```
ShellToast toast = new ShellToast(); 
toast.Title = "My app"; 
toast.Content = "Hello from my app's background task!"; 
toast.Show();
```

For some reason, this doesn't display anything if your app is already running. If you want to display a message then, you can use MessageBox.Show() (if you're OK forcing the user to click OK), or you can use the [Coding4Fun Tools](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-Toast-Prompt-in-depth) that Haider links to.

Answer (score 0):

It would be fairly straight forward to reproduce the visual effect of a toast from within your app. You could use a fixed height, full width canvas with a TextBlock control and animate it's appearance using a storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

How to bind toast notification with schedule in windows phone